# How to show accept terms and conditions window after click on application exe file

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using Electron Builder to create a build for my app. I want an accept terms and condition window will show with checkbox and if user select checkbox and click on continue only then app will get installed otherwise exit the installation.How can i do it in electornjs.

Answer (score 4):

As the document mentioned:

> license String - The path to EULA license file. Defaults to license.txt or eula.txt (or uppercase variants). In addition to txt,rtfandhtmlsupported (don't forget to usetarget=”_blank”` for links).

https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis

So in your package.json build part, try to use it like this:

```
{
    "appId": "yourappid",
    "productName": "your-product",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2020 your company",
    "directories": {
      "app": "www"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "license": "LICENSE.txt", // <- Put your license name here.
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

And put the `LICENSE.txt` file along-side your package.json file:

```
LICENSE

Here is my example license.
```

After building:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Anduin, I tried the same above steps and i am using license.html file but during first time installation the EULA windows shows blank white area https://i.imgur.com/cS4QHgD.png                                                                            
 and when i move the mouse curser on the blank area and click on it then it shows license text https://i.imgur.com/PUQ4aeG.png                                                         
 and after that if i click on exe file any no of times it shows EULA https://i.imgur.com/mO56rNr.png  but for first time on machine it shows nothing.

Comment: Sorry about that. I couldn't repro your error info. You can try my code and it runs just fine: https://github.com/AiursoftWeb/Kahla.App/blob/dev/publish.sh  I can't help you further. If you can locate the error please submit an issue to the electron builder team. Thanks.